# How to recognize a larger object and then some tiny ones in it in a picture?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I want to identify the fittings of the transmission line first, and then the micro parts such as bolt and pin. I may have to train a model using tensorflow and will apply in UAV inspection. Any suggestions?(existed or related algorithm/paper/idea) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can you instance segmentation. Annotate at pixel level the bolts and pins, you can then train Mask RCNN. Hope it helps?